# How to insert the author picture in the biography picture box of the IEEE LaTeX Template

Tags: graphics, ieeetran

How do I put the author picture in the picture frame box of a journal paper? I tried using this code but the picture wasn't placed in the box, it is outside the box. Here is the code:

```
\begin{biography}{{\includegraphics[width=25mm,height=32mm,clip,keepaspectratio]{a.eps}}}
Name ... was born in ... more text.
\end{biography}
```

Comment: Hint, by indenting your code with four spaces, it gets put in a code block. :)

Answer (score 12):

You're using the wrong biography environment. You need to use the `IEEEbiography` environment. Here is the correct code:

```
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{a.eps}}]%
{name}
was born in ... on ... more text.
\end{IEEEbiography}
```

Comment: In `ieee.cls` (as IEEE is in the title) of 2000/01/11 there's no `IEEEbiography` environment, but a `biography` environment with optional argument for the picture file name. I confirm your solution works with `IEEEtran` though, as the tag may lead to.

Answer (score 4):

The question has also been posted on LaTeX-Community.org: [IEEE.cls Template & Author Photo](http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=10026&#p62916).

As I wrote there: the `biography` environment works without `\includegraphics`, and with square brackets, since the picture argument is optional:

```
\begin{biography}[a.eps]{name}
  was born in  ... on ...
\end{biography}
```

Comment: I tried doing this and it does not work. Do you have any other suggestions to get this working.

Comment: @user62089 Perhaps post a new question with details. "does not work" isn't enough, since for me it does. Your situation might be something different.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (May 2016):

```
\begin{biography}[
{
\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{my-face.jpg}
}
]
{John Smith}
received a B.S. and M.S. in blah blah blah...
\end{biography}
```

I'm using the file `ieeeconf.cls` which begins

```
%% IEEEtran.cls 2002/11/18 version V1.6b
%% ...
```

I think you can download it [here](https://www.ualberta.ca/~robio12/ieeeconf.cls).

Comment: Isn't that the same answer as the one by nickb, just with more spaces?

Comment: I needed to replace `IEEEbiography` with `biography` as Stefan noted. Also, I thought it would be helpful to include a link to the `cls` file in question.