# How to add the picture of authors in the biography section of two-column elsevier templat

Tags: els-cas, biography

I wanna add the picture of authors to the biography section of my paper. I use Template article for cas-dc document class for double column output. But the picture boxes overlap with other writings as follows:

[image]

My code is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fleqn,twocolumn]{cas-dc}


\bio{figs/pic1}
Author biography with author photo.
Author biography. Author biography. Author biography.
Author biography. Author biography. Author biography.
Author biography. Author biography. Author biography.
Author biography. Author biography. Author biography.
\endbio
```

How can I avoid this overlaping?

Comment: Have a look to: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45010/how-to-insert-the-author-picture-in-the-biography-picture-box-of-the-ieee-latex/45012

Comment: @SergioCavero I don't want to use ieee class because I used elsevier document class.

Comment: Have a look to other answers, not just the first one.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Sorry, I cannot reproduce your problem. At least not with the code snippet you provided, since it seems to lack necessary information. Could you please provide a compilable example that produces your problem? See the [lipsum package](https://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum?lang=de) if you need some dummy text.

Answer (score 0):

just add many `\\` to remove overlapping

```
\bio{figs/pic1.png}
Author biography with author photo.
Author biography. Author biography. Author biography.
Author biography. Author biography. Author biography.
Author biography. Author biography. Author biography.
Author biography. Author biography. Author biography. \\ \\ \\ \\
\endbio
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is not clear how this would prevent the image from overlapping text left to the biography section.